# Knowing if async function succeeded or failed when that function already catches error?

Tags: javascript

I have structure of my app set up where I use functions like this, that are scoped to "Auth" for example:

```
  async function authenticate(email) {
    let success = false;
    try {
      if (email) {
        if (!validEmail(email)) {
          console.error('Invalid email');
        } else {
          await APIAuthenticate(email);
          success = true;
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
    return success;
  }
```

As you can see there is one inconvenience there with `success` variable, it is there because I need to use `authenticate` function inside another view file to reroute user once authentication is successful (I don't want to reroute user within `authenticate` function itself in order to keep them as separate concerns and not import routing logic into auth).

At the moment I use it like so

```
// MyView.js
const success await authenticate("some@email.com");
if (success) {
  router.push("/dashboard")
}
```

In general it works, but I wanted to ask if there is a solution that won't require me manually tracking `success` variable inside `authenticate()` function?

Comment: Why not move `try.. catch` out of `authenticate` and wrap external call with it?

Comment: @hindmost trying to handle errors within these functions, to keep views a tad cleaner

Comment: Usually one puts `try.. catch` in outermost block. However if you want to get rid your view of `try.. catch` you may wrap `authenticate` with another function handling errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly do you mean, but the `success` is actually not needed in `authenticate()`. Just handle it with `throw` and `catch`.

```
  async function authenticate(email) {
    try {
      if (email) {
        if (!validEmail(email)) {
          throw new Error('Invalid email');
        } else {
          await APIAuthenticate(email);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```